# Type annotation for function that doesn't expose a generic type

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using `react-native-navigation` with `@types/react-native-navigation`. The way that this works is that all of your registered React Native components automatically get a `this.props.navigator`.

`navigator` has a `push` method, but it doesn't allow for any type arguments. It has a property called `passProps` which allow you to pass properties to the page you're navigating to, but there's no way to annotate the types of the props you are passing which should match the props of the screen you're navingating to. For example:

```
export interface BioProps { username: string }
export class BioScreen extends React.Component<BioProps> {}

this.props.navigator.push({
  screen: 'bio.BioScreen',
  title: 'foo',
  passProps: {
    username,
  }
});
```

In this case I want `passProps` to be the same type as `BioProps` for type safety. However, there is nothing like `.push<BioProps>` that would allow you to do this.

Is there any way to enforce type safety when it's not built into the definitions?

Answer (score 1):

You can augment the `Navigator` interface from the module to add a generic overload that will enforce `props` to be of a specific type:

```
// react-native-navigation-augmented.ts
import { Navigation, NavigationComponentProps } from 'react-native-navigation';
declare module 'react-native-navigation'{
    export interface Navigator {
        push<T>(params: PushedScreen & { passProps: T }): void
    }
}


// Otherfile.ts
/// <reference path="./react-native-navigation-augmented.ts" />
this.props.navigator.push<BioProps>({
    screen: 'bio.BioScreen',
    title: 'Pushed Screen',
    // Will cause an error if username is not present or of a different type
    passProps: {
        username: ""
    }
});
```